# Go to Login screen on browser change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating one MVC application wherein I have a login screen. When a user successfully logs in, he is able to see his/her home screen. At this moment if I open the URL in another browser, the user is already logged in. What I want is, log in screen should appear on opening url in different browser.

This is my LoginController index method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

This is the login function :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogIn(string email, string password)
{  
}
```

In web.config I have the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login/LogIn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: What happens if you open a different browser? i.e. if you're using Google Chrome, open the site in Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Comment: put this in your _Layout.cshtml to see if you really are logged in. "@User.Identity.Name". This will output the username of the user, if you don't see the username, then you aren't logged in and something is wrong with your authentication attributes which is causing some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Forms authentication uses cookies to track authenticated users. Cookies are shared across browser screens and tabs. That's how all browsers work an is totally expected behavior. You will observe the same behavior with all major websites.

If you want to achieve that you will have to invent your own way to track authenticated users and not rely on the built-in Forms Authentication mechanism. IIRC Forms Authentication also allows for sending the currently authenticated user in the url but I am not sure that this works very well with ASP.NET MVC routing:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/LogIn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseUri" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: It also has the side-effect of producing grotesque URLs which aren't appropriate for sharing with other users.

Comment: Yes, that's why nobody recommends or uses it.

Answer (score 0):

The home screen should only be available to those logged in so you need to remove the `[AllowAnonymous]` on the home screen action (`Index`?) and add the `[Authorize]` attribute; If the user then attempts to navigate to here without being logged in, they will be redirected to the login screen via the standard forms authentication process.

Should the login view be the default view for the application? If so, you should add a route for an empty url that maps to the `LoginController` `LogIn` action.

Comment: Yes my login view is the default view for which route excists in Global.ascx : routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: Do i have to add one more route ?

Comment: Also if I add authorize attribut instead of AllowAnonymous, then after loggin in I get error, resource type not found.